# Google maps with ngmap mobile issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, mobile, ng-map

I'm using google maps with `ngmap` in an angular application
and I'm having an issue with a `custom marker`.

My `custom marker` has an `input` field inside to set a custom name for my location.
The problem is that on mobile (Android & iOS) I cannot access this field to write into. (Basically I cannot tap on the input field)
Do you have any idea on why would that happen?

I've got my code [here](http://codepen.io/razvan-tudosa/pen/KVyoWm?editors=101) to see this thing in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="infobox">
  <div class="infobox__custom-name">
    <input autofocus type="text" ng-model="vm.eventLocation.name" ng-click="vm.click($event)">
  </div>
  <div class="infobox__address">{{vm.eventLocation.address}}</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
 vm.click = function(e) {
    e.target.focus();
  }
```

Comment: It's exactly how I solved my problem. Even though I've created a directive for myself to do that. Nevertheless I will accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks having shared also your idea